# How can I use Bicep module to pair variables and array and create names for Azure Service Bus queues?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-bicep

How to pair the variables and array together using bicep module?

```
param company string
param environment string
param queuesName array = [
company1
company2
company3
]
```

To write the bicep module to pair these together in servicebusQueues
for example : company + environment + company1 ,company + environment + company2
Here company and environment are same for all but queuesName getting changed everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what the wider context is, but....

```
param company string = 'Contoso'
param environment string = 'Dev'
param queuesName array = [
'company1'
'company2'
'company3'
]

var fullQueueNames = [for queueName in queuesName: '${company}-${environment}-${queueName}' ]
```

This creates an array which contains the 3 concatenated values;

```
"Contoso-Dev-company1"
"Contoso-Dev-company2"
"Contoso-Dev-company3"
```

I can then go off and create the servicebus and queue;

```
param company string = 'Contoso'
param environment string = 'Dev'
param queuesName array = [ 'company1', 'company2', 'company3']
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var fullQueueNames = [for queueName in queuesName: '${company}-${environment}-${queueName}' ]

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2021-11-01' = {
  name: company
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource serviceBusQueue 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues@2021-11-01' = [for queueName in fullQueueNames : {
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  name: queueName
  properties: {
    lockDuration: 'PT5M'
    maxSizeInMegabytes: 1024
    requiresDuplicateDetection: false
    requiresSession: false
    defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: false
    duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'PT10M'
    maxDeliveryCount: 10
    autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    enablePartitioning: false
    enableExpress: false
  }
}]
```